# Google (maybe the browser?) not recognizing USB webcam

Tags: usb, permissions, firefox, webcam, camera

First time here, thank you for all your wonderful work.
I run (K)ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and am having a little trouble with my webcam. Cheese, fswebcam, vlc all recognize and start the device, but Google meet simply returns "No camera found". Zoom (also in browser) similarly does not detect the camera. I've tried in both Firefox as well as Opera, and neither work. The application asks for permission for audio, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with privacy or permissions... a missing driver maybe? Web searches didn't seem to provide any workarounds, so I came here. Relevant info below.

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:0013 SN TECH    K66 Gaming Keyboard̖
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia USB Live Camcra
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and

```
$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
```

and

```
$ lsmod |grep uvcvideo
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

There's no branding on the camera itself, though it does list "Unzano HD620" on the back.
Here's a link to the amazon listing, if that's helpful: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07V3CG6D9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V3CG6D9)

Any and all help would be appreciated, as I'm going to be teaching online in the next month or so and would really love to not use my phone. The product's packaging specifically lists compatibility for Ubuntu 10.04 (and above) as well as Linux 2.6.24 (and above). THANKS!!

Comment: You can install `guvcview` and open it to verify if the camera is being recognized by the system.

Comment: `guvcview` and the others I listed recognize the camera, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the system. Functionality for adjusting aperture, exposure, and focus all work as well. It's literally just in online/streaming services that it doesn't get picked up, hence why I thought it might have to do with permissions.