# Webcam not working nor Detected in any Browser but working in other Programs

Tags: usb, 20.04, webcam, browser, camera

A thing to mention is that I am not experienced in Linux generally as I've switched only recently, so pardon me if I miss out on or have not done something obvious.
I have reviewed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261283/google-maybe-the-browser-not-recognizing-usb-webcam) thread and have a very similar problem. Seems like the answers to the problem are very limited, thus I'm making this thread.
My webcam is recognized on programs like Discord but not on any online-hosting program like Chrome, Brave & etc. It's working well on programs that do recognize it.
I have tried fixing the problem by trying to make myself a virtual camera by using OBS, albeit it just exacerbated the issue and it still was not detected by any website on any browser. I can't list how many tutorials I have watched on this problem and how deeply I have dug myself from a clean version of Ubuntu by building dependencies, running modules and etc.

`$ ls /dev/video*`

```
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2  /dev/video3
```

`$ lsmod |grep uvcvideo`

```
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              225280  4 videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2loopback,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did I not list something important? Am I missing drivers?
I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04. I've heard that the Linux Community is very helpful and friendly, so please don't disappoint my impressions with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exact same problem. Everything was working but I just tried my webcam in a number of browsers and it isn't showing up any more. Works fine in Skype and Cheese. I plugged in another webcam but that isn't recognised in browsers, either.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line (Ctrl-Alt-T):

```
ls -l /dev/video*
```

(note the difference (the "`-l`option, read `man ls`) to see the permissions (probably `crw-rw----`) and owner/group of the device (probably `root:video`).

Are you a member of the `video` group?

```
id
```

If "`video`" is in the list of groups, Stop Reading Now! This Answer doesn't apply.

If you're not a member of the `video` group, add yourself:

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Followed by a logout/login - group changes take effect at `login`.